# How to find if any element of the list is present in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary, optimization

I have the following code:

```
fileTypes = ["photo", "audio"]
arg = {"photo": "123"}
is_file = True if [True for f in fileTypes if f in arg.keys()] else False
```

The `is_file` output is `True`, if "photo" or "audio" is one of the keys of `arg`.

I want `is_file` to  return `False` or one of file type, if it is set in `arg`. One of the  file types can be in the arg dict.

Also, I think this is not optimized. I'd like a better alternative.

Comment: You mean like? `is_file = [f in arg for f in fileTypes]` or perhaps `is_file = any(f in arg for f in fileTypes)`

Comment: Yes, something like that! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

What about `any()`?

```
from timeit import timeit

def list_comprehension_method():

    fileTypes = ["photo", "audio"]
    arg = {"photo": "123"}
    return True if [True for f in fileTypes if f in arg.keys()] else False

def any_method():

    fileTypes = ["photo", "audio"]
    arg = {"photo": "123"}
    return any(f in arg.keys() for f in fileTypes)


number = 1000

print('any_method:                 ', timeit('f()', 'from __main__ import any_method as f', number=number))
print('list_comprehension_method:  ', timeit('f()', 'from __main__ import list_comprehension_method as f', number=number))
```

Python 2.7:

```
any_method:                 0.001070976257324218
list_comprehension_method:  0.001577138900756836
```

Python 3.6:

```
any_method:                  0.0013788840005872771
list_comprehension_method:   0.0015097739960765466
```

Comment: You might want to show the results of your timings too. Also no need for the `.keys()` call when using the `in` operator

Comment: @Chris_Rands Sure, I will add the `timeit` results to the post! After I submitted, I noticed that you had the same idea, but 10 minutes before me, posted as a comment... :) I see people posting answers as comments often, and I never get why... May I ask why did you prefer to post in a comment instead of in an answer? Just curious. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for adding times; i wasn't actually sure i had the answer they wanted